# Whitespace delimited table to CSV with standard text processing tools

Tags: linux, text-processing, gnu, text-formatting

I have the following data table:

```
ssh     22/tcp  0.182286        # Secure Shell Login
linuxconf   98/tcp  0.000088 
tacnews    98/udp   0.000560    # TAC News
```

from which I wish to generate a CSV file in the following format:

```
ssh,22,tcp,Secure Shell Login
linuxconf,98,tcp,
tacnews,98,udp,Tac News
```

I am discarding the fractional decimal number and including the description without the '# ' if it exists.

I see the data as a bunch of fields (forgive the faux regex):

```
^{1}\s+{2}/{3}\s+{4}\s+# {5}$
```

For which I would output:

```
{1},{2},{3},{5}
```

What would be the most simplest and most appropriate tool to do this? I'd be grateful for help with the syntax to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best tool for something like this is probably `sed`, here is a working example using extended regular expressions:

```
sed -E 's:^([^ ]*)\s+([^/]*)/([^ ]*)\s+[^ ]*\s*#?\s*(.*):\1,\2,\3,\4:' file
```

Or if your input might be tab delimited:

```
sed -E 's:^([^[:space:]]*)\s+([^/]*)/([^[:space:]]*)\s+[^[:space:]]*\s*#?\s*(.*):\1,\2,\3,\4:' file
```

Output:

```
ssh,22,tcp,Secure Shell Login
linuxconf,98,tcp,
tacnews,98,udp,TAC News
```

#### Explanation

- `s:::` use colon as the expression delimiter
- `^([^ ]*)` first capture group, match sequence of non-space characters at the beginning of the line
- `\s+` ignore space
- `([^/]*)` second capture group, match upto a slash
- `/` ignore slash
- `([^ ]*)` third capture group, match sequence of non-space characters
- `\s+` ignore space
- `[^ ]*` ignore decimal number
- `\s*#?\s*` ignore space and optional hash
- `(.*)` fourth capture group, the rest of the line

Comment: Thor thank you for the quick response aswell as the explanation. It's not quite working for me. I have tried on the nmap-services file but it's giving:  
`ssh,22,tcp      0.182286        #,Shell Login`  
I ran:  
`sed -E 's:^([^ ]*)\s+([^/]*)/([^ ]*)\s+[^ ]*\s*#?\s*(.*):\1,\2,\3,\4:' nmap-services > nmap-services.csv`

Comment: @user1330734: I have added an alternative that supports tab delimited input

Answer (score 1):

I'd use perl: You have the regex sketched out, this fills in the gaps.

```
perl -lne '
    / (\S+)     \s+      # non-whitespace followed by whitespace
      (\d+)     \/       # digits followed by slash
      (\S+)     \s+      # non-whitespace followed by whitespace
      (\S+)     \s*      # non-whitespace followed by optional whitespace
      (?:\#\s)? (.*)     # possibly a hash+space and whatever follows
    /x and print "$1,$2,$3,$4,$5"' file
```